# Referencing remote MS SQL databases from Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have inherited a large legacy system on MS SQL2008 R2.

There are a large number of stored procedures that reference another database:

```
select * from MySeparateDatabase_LIVE.dbo.MyTable
select * from MySeparateDatabase_STAGING.dbo.MyTable
select * from MySeparateDatabase_TEST.dbo.MyTable
```

Unfortunately all the live, staging and test databases are on the same SQL instance and company constraints mean this will not change soon.

The problem comes trying to push changes from test to staging and live. It requires an amount of manual editing or find/replace - which introduces potential errors on a critical system.

What techniques can I employ to use exactly the same SP on each database?

Comment: Can you provide a better piece of example code. There's no reason your example code won't execute on each db.

Comment: @gvee the first query is in a database called, say, `dbLive`, the second query is in a database called, say, `dbStage`. Each database should reference its "companion" database, but in order to do that, the code currently has to change when it is moved from the test db to the staging db.

Comment: If you are working with stored procedures you could pass your MySeparateDatabase_XXX part as a parameter. This would move your problem to the part where your SP's are called, so this may or may not be a solution.

Comment: @Sam but then you need all of the code to be dynamic SQL, and if the code is called from other procedures within the database, that doesn't really solve the problem and actually makes it quite a bit messier.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The penny dropped. I had something specific in mind that wasn't relevant. Previous comments removed to get rid of the clutter. Short story: use synonyms :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Create `SYNONYM`s](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx), e.g. In your test db:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.MyTable FOR MySeparateDatabase_Test.dbo.MyTable;
```

And in staging:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.MyTable FOR MySeparateDatabase_Staging.dbo.MyTable;
```

This provides a layer of abstraction, and allows you to have the same code in each database. This way you can deploy the different synonyms once but the procedures can be identical (and they would only reference `dbo.MyTable` without the database prefix, letting the synonym redirect to the right database). A stored procedure in the test db will reference the table in the other test database, a stored procedure in the staging db will reference the table in the other staging database, etc.

Comment: Better yet, auto-generate them, that's how I do this.

Comment: @RBarryYoung can you elaborate?

Comment: I have procedures that I call passing in a DBname that will drop all synonyms in a certain schema of the current DB, the create new synonyms in that same schema using either a name-list table or the names of all tables in the `dbo` schema of the named DB as a guide.  Makes it very easy to switch phases and/or deploy to production.

Comment: The CREATE SYNONYM command - does this store in tempDB?   ie can I use this in situations where live and staging are on the same server instance, or would you not be able to use it in this situation?

Comment: @simon831 no, this has nothing to do with tempdb; synonyms are database-scoped, so they live in the database where you create them. If live and staging are on the same server instance, then there's really no difference - as long as you have two different databases, you can have a synonym in each with the same name that point to different resources. That's the whole point. Now, if you're trying to get one synonym to point to two different things in the same database, that is not going to work (unless you drop and re-create the synonym depending on context).